# How to use quotes in calling a command line tool from shell

Tags: shell

I have a self made command line tool (uses golang flags) that works very well.
The command line Parameter contains listing of a directory (ls)
When I start it from a script, I have problems with the quotes, that define the parameter text:

```
./Cmdlinetool -text='FileA FileB FileC'
```

If I use it with a script, the output is:

```
Parameter Text:     'FileA 
tail: [ FileB FileC']
```

If I use it without a script, the output is:

```
Parameter Text:     FileA FileB FileC
tail: [ ]
```

The script looks like this, it replaces all line breaks with spaces:  tr '\n' ' '

```
tmp="'$(ls)'"
TEXT="$(echo $tmp | tr '\n' ' ' )"
./Cmdlinetool -text=$TEXT
```

Also masking the quotes with \ does not help,
I also tried "   and '

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

1. `tmp="'$(ls)'"`

   You put literal single quotes into the tmp string: The first and last characters in the string are quote characters.
2. `./Cmdlinetool -text=$TEXT`

   You fail to quote the variable. This allows the shell to do "word splitting", so you're actually invoking the tool like this:

   ```
    ./Cmdlinetool -text="'File1" "File2" "File3'"
   ```

Do this instead:

```sh
files=(*)  # an array of the filenames in this directory
./Cmdlinetool -text="${files[*]}"    # a space separated string of the array contents
```

Comment: Works great thank you very much for the quick and great formulated answer :-) I first thought that files=(*) is pseudocode before I recognised that it is not...

Comment: Take this as a lesson from this exchange: in shell, always quote your `"$variables"` (unless you know the specific side-effect you want to achieve, and the risks).